# Homogenous Differential Equation Substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the homogenous differential equation

$$(x+ye^{y/x})dx -xe^{y/x} dy=0$$

With initial condition that $y(1)=0$. Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: As usual for homogeneous ODE, change of variable $y(x)=x\,u(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Devide the equation by $xdx$

$$(1+y/xe^{y/x}) -e^{y/x} dy/dx=0$$

and use the substitution $y=zx$

$$(1+ze^z) -e^z dy/dx=0$$

with $ dy/dx=xdz/dx+z$

$$(1+ze^z) -e^z (xdz/dx +z)=0$$
$$\implies 1-xe^zdz/dx=0$$

Solve this separable ODE and resubstitute.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
x+ye^{\frac{y}{x}}=xe^{\frac{y}{x}}\frac{dy}{dx}
\end{eqnarray*}
let $u= \frac{y}{x}$ so $\frac{dy}{dx}=u+x \frac{du}{dx}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
1+ue^u=e^u \left(u+x\frac{du}{dx} \right) \\
\frac{dx}{x}=e^u du \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Integrate & use the initial condition 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln x =e^u-1 .
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute back in & we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{blue}{y = x \ln (1+ \ln x ) }.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging the differential equation:$$(x+ye^{\frac{y}{x}})dx=xe^{\frac{y}{x}}dy$$
$$e^{-\frac{y}{x}}+\frac{y}{x}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Using the substitution $y=ux$$\rightarrow$$\frac{dy}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx}$

Then,$$e^{-u}+u=u+x\frac{du}{dx},$$
So the original differential eqaution reduces to:$$\frac{1}{x}dx=e^{u}du$$
That's easy to solve.